# Implementing Interface to a Generic method parameter VS Implementing Interface to an method argument

Tags: c#, .net

Im quite confused by what i found in a programming course.

In brief - I found a method which has that construction:

```
    public void MethodA<T>(T a) where T : IComparable
    {
        //...
    }
```

And as far as i know - the same exact effect we can can achive using just this:

```
    public void MethodB(IComparable a)
    {
       //... 
    }
```

Are those two ways differ from each other somehow and has one of them any advantage over the other? If so, how could look a scenario where one of them is better to use?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: in the first case the method will have more specific type as parameter but that type would be inheriting fro ICmparable as well, while in second case you would have to pass the object in type IComparable

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess if you have a `struct` that implements `IComparable`, calling the first method will not box that `struct` while calling the second would require boxing.

Comment: You can always go `public void MethodA<T>(IComparable<T> t)`.

Answer (score 5):

I was curious so I made a little testcode myself:

```
public interface ITest
{
    int Value { get; set; }
}
public struct TestStruct : ITest
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

private static void TestMethodGeneric<T>(T value) where T : ITest
{
}
private static void TestMethodNonGeneric(ITest value)
{
}
```

And in my main method I use both calls:

```
TestStruct ts = new TestStruct {Value = 10};
TestMethodNonGeneric(ts);
TestMethodGeneric(ts);
```

And this is the resulting IL code:

Non-generic:

```
IL_0031: ldloc.0      // ts
IL_0032: box          Tests.Program/*02000002*//TestStruct/*02000026*/
IL_0037: call         void Tests.Program/*02000002*/::TestMethodNonGeneric(class Tests.Program/*02000002*//ITest/*02000025*/)/*06000002*/
IL_003c: nop
```

Generic:

```
IL_0059: ldloc.0      // ts
IL_005a: call         void Tests.Program/*02000002*/::TestMethodGeneric<valuetype Tests.Program/*02000002*//TestStruct/*02000026*/>(!!0/*valuetype Tests.Program*//*02000002*//*/TestStruct*//*02000026*//**/)/*06000001*/
IL_005f: nop
```

So you see, in the generic version, the specific type is used and therefor no boxing occurs.
In the non-generic version, the `struct` value has to be casted to `ITest` and so it gets boxed. So the generic version has a (very tiny) performance advantage.

Just my two cents, there maybe other more or less important differences in the two approaches.

Comment: Amazing answer! Thanks!

Comment: I'd personally prefer the strict typing (non-generic) version for this scenario as long as boxing is not a real issue. The generic version looks a little odd. But I can't find a bullet-proof technical argument.